# If the volume of a container is $196~\text{cm}^3$, find the dimensions of the original template.

Tags: quadratics, volume

This is a quadratics problem. The full question reads:

> An open container with a square base is made by cutting $4~\text{cm}$ square pieces out of a piece of tin. If the volume of the container is $196~\text{cm}^3$, find the dimensions of the original template. Let the length of the tinplate be $x~\text{cm}$.

[image: The diagram which accompanies the problem]

I surmise that $x-8~\text{cm}$ is the unspecified length, but I'm unsure about anything else.

Comment: @almagest You may wish to check the expression you just wrote, as  it is not consistent with the diagram.

Comment: Well, $7$ is base-ically right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It's a square though, so shouldn't all of those x values be 7?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought the base was $x+8$. So the equation is $4(x-8)^2=196$ and $x=15$

Comment: Ah I see, you cut 4cm squares off the corners and then fold up the sides.

Comment: @almagest So the dimensions are 15 x 15 cm? Thank you very much!

Comment: @MadBanners But do you see how to get that?

Comment: @almagest Yes; you divide both sides of the equation by 4 to get x^2 on its own. Then you take a square root of 196 to find x. I'm still a bit confused about the relationship between volume and dimensions, though.

Comment: The box has base $x-8$ times $x-8$ and depth $4$. For a rectangular box you just multiply length, width, and depth to get volume.

Comment: @almagest Aha, I see. But a different formula is used here because the box is square?

Comment: No. Length of base = width of base = $x$-8.

Comment: @almagest Okay. But where does 4x^2 derive from?

Comment: The formula is (depth 4) times (length $x-8$) times (width $x-8$)=$4(x-8)^2$. That equals 196, so $x-8=7$, so $x=15$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the box by cutting off the corners of the $x$ cm $\times x$ cm "original template" and folding up the sides:

[image]

Box base area $=\frac{\text{volume}}{\text{height}}=\frac{196}{4} = 49 \text{ cm}^2$

$b = \sqrt{49} = 7$ cm

$x= b+8 = 15 $ cm

---

Alternative answer if the box was *not* specified as square. Then the piece of tin that was used is $x$ cm wide and $y$ cm long, and

\begin{align}(x-8)(y-8) &= 49 \\[2ex]
xy-8x-8y &= 49-64 = -15 \\[2ex]
(x-8)y &=8x-15\\[2ex]
y &=\frac{8x-15}{x-8}
\end{align}

and check that $x=15 \implies y=\frac{7\cdot 15}{7} = 15 \quad\checkmark$

Comment: @almagest Maybe I'm just sleepy but I had a hard time working out what the "cutting 4 cm square pieces out" meant - so I thought a picture would be good